# Is it possible for users to contact each other without knowing their email addresses via Mandrill?

Tags: mandrill

My website allow User A send email to User B through a form. Currently if User B want to reply, he need to login to my website and use the same form.

User A dont know the User B's email address and vice versa.

I would like to allow User B reply to User A directly using his mail client without need to login to my website (while still keep both email addresses confidentially). So User A send a message to User B using the form. User B can reply to user A using his email client, and user B can reply to user A using email client too without reveal their email address.

I was told this is possible with Mandrill Webhook. Is that correct? Can anybody please show me how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is *inbound email processing*.

- First, **create an inbound domain** in your Mandrill dashboard.
- **Set up routes / webhooks** in your dashboard (for example, sending an email to pm@example.com will send a POST to http://example.com/email-processing/pm).
- In your application, **process the received message** and decide if you have to send it to one of your user, and more important, which user.
  To do so, you can **add a unique ID** inside your emails. So you just have to read this ID when you receive an email, and you know who is the sender and who should be the receiver. Of course, you should also check the sender's email address.

More informations about the first two steps: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Jean Bergeron, thanks a lot for reply my question. That is a very comprehensive answer! I believe that will solve my problem. Thank you very much! :)